# Cannot use LOAD DATA or LOAD DATA LOCAL

Tags: mysql, linux, csv, load, workbench

I'm trying to load a csv file in Workbench as follows:

```
load data infile '/home/linux/Documentos/air/1987.csv'
into table mydata
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\ n';
```

Which reports the following error:

> Error Code: 29 File '/home/linux/Documentos/air/1987.csv' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

But if use:

```
load data local infile '/home/linux/Documentos/air/1987.csv'
into table mydata
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\ n';
```

The reported error is:

> Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version.

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 distribution and 6.3.4.0 Workbench.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What version of MySQL (not MySQL Workbench) are you running?

Comment: I am using MySQL Server 5.6.

Comment: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is disabled by default in 5.6. See the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data-local.html